# Translated taxonomy term pages are returning 403 errors

Tags: i18n-l10n

Even with the highest level of access (Super-Admin), the site displays a permission denied error when trying to edit the translation of certain translated taxonomy terms:

[image]

*[Translation: System
Access denied
You are not allowed to access this page.]*

What makes it weirder is that similar sibling pages are being accessed just fine. For example:

https://example.com/ar/taxonomy/term/360 => fine

https://example.com/ar/taxonomy/term/77 => 403 error

Using the tmgmt extension on Drupal 9.5.9. Any help appreciated.

Comment: *Super-Admin* does not sound like a default Drupal role name. By default Drupal's role name for the highest level of access is just *Administrator*. You can cross-check this setting at `/admin/people/role-settings`

Comment: Thanks, I assume the dev team must have renamed or created new roles and permissions. Closest we have to _Administrator_ is _Site Admin_, but that role possesses lower admin abilities than _Super Admin_. Thanks for the input tho!